# Generate migrations and add fields on a command line

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am writing a library for which I need migrations to run on the user’s system who is using the library and I will keep the schema inside the library. I have found `mix phx.gen.schema` but it creates schemas with migrations. In `mix ecto.gen.migration` we couldn’t pass fields names, just the migration name.
I also looked at the `mix generators` but they create boilerplate code that I don’t need.
Is there any way we can create just migrations with fields names on a command line.
Thanks.

Comment: I would go with your own [`Mix.Task`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Task.html#content), that either creates a migration for the user to run or runs it explicitly.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin  Thanks for your valuable suggestion.Yes that's the idea to create a mix task, but I am confused how to handle migrations in that. if I  run mix ecto.gen.migration it will only create a migration without any fields. How to insert fields in that migration in the same task? that's what confusing me.

Comment: In your own task, you can write any arbitrary code, e. g. use [`Ecto.Migrator`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migrator.html?) or like.

Comment: Or, you can take an inspiration from [`Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Gen.Migration`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto_sql/blob/v3.4.5/lib/mix/tasks/ecto.gen.migration.ex#L112-L119]) and create a migration as you wish to be run by user. I suggest to not use existing tasks at all, use your own instead and instruct the user to run it.